# How set radio button list with postfix the text after radio icon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am using asp.net radio button list where it is rendering the following html. But problem is to how to render text of radio button next to radio icon. currently it is showing on bottom side of radio icon.
 it is rendering following html. there are ton of space in between these two radio even though not render after radio button.

```html
<td>
    <table id="MainContent_rdlRunType" style="width:50%;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="MainContent_rdlRunType_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$rdlRunType" value="0" checked="checked">
                    <label for="MainContent_rdlRunType_0">True</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="MainContent_rdlRunType_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$rdlRunType" value="1">
                    <label for="MainContent_rdlRunType_1">False</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>                                                            
</td>
```

I want to render like

```
radio button True radio False.
```

Is there any way to do it like this?

Comment: The label is sitting directly next to the radio button?

Comment: Run your code snippet?

Comment: @Aaron - I want to sit label next to radio button, it is currently on below of radio button.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1fLsqmn7/?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because you are using inline style `width: 50%` in your table. You can remove it:

```html
<table id="MainContent_rdlRunType">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="MainContent_rdlRunType_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$rdlRunType" value="0" checked="checked">
                <label for="MainContent_rdlRunType_0">True</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="MainContent_rdlRunType_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$rdlRunType" value="1">
                <label for="MainContent_rdlRunType_1">False</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```